# Determining how long the user is logged on to Windows

Tags: windows

The need arose, in our product, to determine how long the current user has been logged on to Windows (specifically, Vista). It seems there is no straight forward API function for this and I couldn't find anything relevant with WMI (although I'm no expert with WMI, so I might have missed something).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people not familiar with WMI (like me), here are some links:

- MSDN page on using WMI from various languages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964(VS.85).aspx
- reference about Win32_Session: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394422(VS.85).aspx, but the objects in Win32_session are of type Win32_LogonSession (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189(VS.85).aspx), which has more interesting properties.
- [WMI Explorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm) - a tool you can use to easily run queries like the one Michal posted.

And here's example querying Win32_Session from VBS:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set sessions = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("select * from Win32_Session")

For Each objSession in sessions
   Wscript.Echo objSession.StartTime
Next
```

It alerts 6 sessions for my personal computer, perhaps you can filter by LogonType to only list the real ("interactive") users. I couldn't see how you can select the session of the "current user".

[edit] and here's a result from Google to your problem: http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3755

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use CMD or PowerShell to query the users using the command:

```
C:\> query user
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
john                  rdp-tcp#56          9  Active          .  5/3/2020   10:19 AM
max                   rdp-tcp#5          30  Active    5+23:42  9/4/2020   7:31  PM
yee                                      35  Disc         6:41  10/14/2020 6:37  PM
mohammd               rdp-tcp#3          37  Active          .  10/15/2020 7:51  AM
```

Comment: This appears to [only apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user) to Windows Server.

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10.  So it is not just for a server.  The method by Gnat was giving a date of several months ago.

Comment: quser is flaky. The "Server" is running Windows 10 Pro.   When I connect with Citrix Connect, the state is always active, even when disconnected.  If I RDP to it and then disconnect, the state is correct but the idle time is still always "."  or 1.  It never goes up and the user is disconnected....  which is about as idle as a user can be.  Since we are using Citrix and need to free it up, quser is not going to be the way.  It is untrustworthy.

Answer (score 4):

In Powershell and WMI, the following one-line command will return a list of objects showing the user and the time they logged on.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkloginprofile | ? {$_.lastlogon -ne $null} | % {[PSCustomObject]@{User=$_.caption; LastLogon=[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.lastlogon)}}
```

Explanation:

- Retrieve the list of logged in users from WMI
- Filter out any non-interactive users (effectively removes `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`)
- Reformats the user and logon time for readability

References:

- The WMI object to use: https://forum.sysinternals.com/topic3755.html
- Formatting the date/time: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/08/12/get-systemuptime-and-working-with-the-wmi-date-format/

Comment: i believe this is very questionable of what is meant here by "last login". The name suggests it is the facade for `NetUserGetInfo` API with output format `11` or `21`. However, for that function "login" means ANY act of authentificaiton, not the "interactive session" start. You put a laptop to sleep and back - and the coutner is zeroed. You press Win+L and go back - the counter is zeroed. You run any application with User Access Control Elevation - and the counter is zeroed. You connect from remote computer to the local shared folder using credentials - and it is zeroed yet again. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

In WMI do: "select * from Win32_Session"
there you'll have "StartTime" value.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using WMI, the Win32Session is a great start. As well, it should be pointed out that if you're on a network you can use Win32_NetworkLoginProfile to get all sorts of info.

```
Set logins = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
For Each objSession in logins
   Wscript.Echo objSession.LastLogon
Next
```

Other bits of info you can collect include the user name, last logoff, as well as various profile related stuff.

Comment: `Win32_NetworkLoginProfile` most probably not... see my comment above on `NetUserGetInfo`